# JavaScript and HTML form with 1 out of 2 text fields require inputs

Tags: javascript, html

So im making a sign up form and in the sign up form i need the user to put input in 1 of 2 text fields, i already have code that requires text for one field however i need to expand on this code for it to be able to check over 2 fields.

Below is an example of the code with the corresponding HTML that i have.
The fields that i want the new code to check are called 'ctt' and 'bcn'.

Im normally bad at explaining so if anyone needs me to explain any further in what im trying to do dont hesitate to ask.

```js
{
 var username = document.querySelector('input[name="username"]');
username.setCustomValidity('Please enter a user name, minimum length of 2 characters, maximum 32 characters');

username.addEventListener('input', function () {
  
  if (this.value.trim() === '') {
    this.setCustomValidity('Please enter a user name, minimum length of 2 characters, maximum 32 characters');
  }
  else {
    this.setCustomValidity('');
  }
}, false);

username.addEventListener('invalid', function () {
  if (this.value.trim() !== '') {
    this.setCustomValidity("Please enter a user name, minimum length of 2 characters, maximum 32 characters");
  }
}, false);
 }
```

```html
<div class="group">
        <div class="col-1">
            <label for="username">Username*</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" minlength="2" maxlength="32" placeholder="username"  required/>
   <span class="validity"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The input field i want the code to read will be below

```
<!-- CTT Number -->
<div class="group">
    <div class="col-1">
        <label for="ctt">CTT Number</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
        <input type="text" id="ctt" name="ctt" pattern="[0-9]{8}" maxlength="8" placeholder="CTT Number" />
        <span class="validity"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- BC Number -->
<div class="group">
    <div class="col-1">
        <label for="bcnum">BC Number</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
        <input type="text" id="bcn" name="bcn" pattern="[0-9]{8}" maxlength="8" placeholder="BC Number"  />
        <span class="validity"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I only see one input there, and I see no references to anything `ctt` or `bcn`.

Comment: i didnt think of putting the input fields in that i want the code to check over, here is the field inputs i want it to check.

Comment: Why do you keep deleting your comment? Put information essential to answering your question in the question itself, and don't abuse comment add/deletes as a way to repeatedly ping people

Comment: sorry didnt mean to just dont know how to put the code snippet inside the comment without it messing up